# Get the row with the largest value from a set of rows from a pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

So I have rows that look like this that are created via a pivot table:

```
uid did size count
101 m   100  5
101 m   75   8
101 m   20   3
101 w   80   7
101 w   100  3
102 m   100  2
102 m   50   1
```

And for each uid did pair I want to get the row with the largest count.

So from this table I want to get this smaller table:

```
101 m 75 8
101 w 80 7
102 m 100 2
```

Because 8,7 and 2 are the rows with the highest count.

Any suggestions on how to do this? There are several thousand rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a top 10 Value filter on the Size column will do what you want. You might need to adjust the "10", and make sure you set the 3rd column to "Sum".

[image]